# How to calculate total time using Carbon

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner at Laravel, and I want to show a total of time using Carbon and I have individual time, just I want to count all total time. How can I do this?

Please see this image:

https://ibb.co/rkNDSDv

**HTML view**

```
     <table class="table table-bordered table- 
          striped" >
             <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Project</th>
              <th>Module </th>
              <th>Work Description</th>
              <th>Start Time</th>
              <th>End Time</th>
              <th>Total Time</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              @foreach($hourlogs as $hourlog)
              @php
                // get total time from minutesa
                $minutes= $hourlog->hour_work;
                $totalhour = floor($minutes / 60);

                $totalHourMin = $totalhour * 60;

                $minutess = $minutes - $totalHourMin;

                 if($minutess  > 9)
                 {
                  $minutess = "" . $minutess;
                 }
                 else { 
                  $minutess = "0" . $minutess;
                  }   
                 $date=$hourlog->date;   
                // Creating timestamp from given date
                $timestamp = strtotime($date);

                // Creating new date format from that timestamp

                $new_date = date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);

                @endphp
                <tr>
                <td>{{$new_date}}</td>
                <td>{{$hourlog->project->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$hourlog->module}}</td>
                <td>{{$hourlog->work_area}}</td>
                <td>{{$hourlog->start_time}}</td>
                <td>{{$hourlog->end_time}}</td>
                <td>{{$totalhour}}:{{$minutess}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td> //get total count time here </td>
                </tr>
               </tfoot>
               </table>
```

Comment: Whats the date format of `start_time`?

Comment: <input type="text"   name="start_time"  id="start_time" value="{{date('h:i')}}" step="any" class="form-control flatpickr-input active start_time preloading-timepicker " >

Comment: I'm bit confuse.it may be `date('h:i a')` ? `a` for (am or pm)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date` facade (Carbon alias) to subtract `start_time` from `end_time` and add each difference to achieve total value, something like this (not tested):

```php
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Module </th>
      <th>Work Description</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
      <th>Total Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @php
      $total = Date::parse('00:00');
    @endphp

    @foreach($hourlogs as $hourlog)
      @php
        $rowTotal = Date::parse($hourlog->end_time)
                        ->sub(Date::parse($hourlog->start_time));

        $total->add($rowTotal);
      @endphp
      <tr>
        <td>{{ Date::parse($hourlog->date)->format('$hourlog->date') }}</td>
        <td>{{$hourlog->project->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$hourlog->module}}</td>
        <td>{{$hourlog->work_area}}</td>
        <td>{{$hourlog->start_time}}</td>
        <td>{{$hourlog->end_time}}</td>
        <td>{{ $rowTotal->format('g:i') }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>{{ $total->format('g:i') }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```